# Returning the value of the first number in a string

Tags: java, regex, string

Hi I'm using general expression to get the first number in a String:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String string = "hellow this is \"width: 32%\" and i know";

        Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("width: (\\d+?)");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        matcher.find();
        System.out.println(Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1)));
     }
}
```

This is a simplified version. This prints out the number 3 but I would like it to print out 32, what am I doing wrong? Could somebody point me in the right direction,
thanks.

Comment: remove the question mark.

Comment: You already seem to have an answer prior to writing this question. There is nothing wrong with answering your own question as long as it will be useful to other people using this site (SO is not a personal KB). The problem here is that your question isn't going to be useful as it very poorly described. Your title asks for the first number in a string, yet your actual code (and answer) suggests you are looking specifically to match a `width` property, so it's all very misleading. Not to mention there is probably plenty of duplicates for this question, so is there really any need to ask at all?

Answer (score 3):

Remove `?`, because `?` after `+` or `*` will do a non-greedy match. So this stops matching once it finds a single match. `\\d+?` matches the first digit and stops matching  the next because it already finds a match.

```
Pattern pattern =  Pattern.compile("width: (\\d+)");
```

Answer (score 2):

with **(\\d+?)** your are wanting number lazily, so it will take the less number it can.

You can use **(\\d+)** to make it greedy.

Answer (score -2):

The correct pattern to use is (To find the first number percentage)

```
Pattern.compile("width: (\\d+?)%");
```

This works perfectly to get the number before the %, hope this helps other people as well.

Comment: (-1) This solution will not find the first number in a string, which is what the question asks for. For example: `"The number 42 is first in this string, but it will find width: 50% instead"`

Comment: You are correct, my question was not written correctly, I was looking to find the first number percentage.

Comment: Your answer is not finding the first percentage, it is finding a number inside the pattern "width: xxx%". The non greedy character is the problem, you are just finding a crappy solution that work here. For exemple, if you have the regexp "(\\d+?)%" : "57% will give you 7%, not 57%"